# Ordering data in new way from stream

Tags: c++, stream, xcode5

If I have lines in a text file that look like this:

```
1    4:48:08   Orvar Steingrimsson                 1979   30 - 39 ara      IS200 
2    4:52:25   Gudni Pall Palsson                  1987   18 - 29 ara      IS870
```

How can I output this data onto a new text file but only listing three things: year - name - time ... so that these two lines would look like this:

```
1979   Orvar Steingrimsson   4:48:08
1987   Gudni Pall Palsson    4:52:25
```

My guess was this:

```
ifstream in("inputfile.txt");
ofstream out("outputfile.txt");
int score, year;
string name, time, group, team;
while (getline(in,str));
in >> score >> time >> name >> year >> group >> team;
//and then do something like this
out << year << name << time << '\n';
```

However I have a feeling I won't be able to loop this through the whole text file and all 200 lines. Any tips appreciated!

Comment: I would use `scanf` for this, but I'm biased towards C's file manipulation functions. In "proper" C++, you'd probably use `>>`. Anyway for your exact problem, you're using the wrong `substr`. You want `str.substr(54,4)`. The one you're using is C-style and doesn't work with `std::string`s.

Comment: Second problem: `'` in C/C++ means character, `"` means string.

Answer (score 0):

After you extract the substring, you can call `strtol()` (or `std::stoi()` if you have C++.11) to convert the string into an integer. Once you have both the year and the line of data, you can store them into some table, perhaps a `std::multimap<>`.

Without C++.11:

```
void process (std::istream &in, std::ostream &out) {
    typedef std::multimap<int, std::string> table_type;
    table_type data_by_year;
    std::string str;
    while (std::getline(in,str)) {
        int year = strtol(str.substr(54, 4).c_str(), 0, 10);
        data_by_year.insert(std::make_pair(year, str));
    }
    for (table_type::iterator i = data_by_year.begin();
         i != data_by_year.end();
         ++i) {
        out << i->second << "\n";
    }
}
```

In C++.11:

```
void process (std::istream &in, std::ostream &out) {
    std::multimap<int, std::string> data_by_year;
    std::string str;
    while (std::getline(in,str)) {
        int year = std::stoi(str.substr(54, 4));
        data_by_year.insert(std::make_pair(year, str));
    }
    for (auto v : data_by_year) {
        out << v.second << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: `std::stoi` requires C++11 support

Comment: @LihO: Hmm... then I could use `auto` and the new `for` syntax too. But the question isn't tagged C++11... Okay, changed to `strtol()`, thanks.

Comment: could someone explain how I use this line?
std::multimap<int, std::string> data_by_year;

Comment: When I attempt this method, I keep getting "use of undeclared identifier data_by_year". So i get that that means I need to identify it, but as what? int, string, char? i have no idea, everything results in an error

Comment: You need `#include <map>`. Also, I updated the answer using `insert()` instead of `[]`, since `multimap<>` doesn't support the `[]` operator (`map<>` does support `[]`, but switched to `multimap<>` so that multiple entries with the same `year` could be stored in the table).

Comment: 404 Not Found. I really appreciate your help though jxh, as I literally do not have any other help available to me.

Comment: You can follow this [link](http://ideone.com/xLdu0T) for a demo. Note that the demo uses `substr(38, 4)` because it matches the input you provided in your question. The posted answer uses `substr(54, 4)` to match the code sample you supplied in your question.

Comment: Seeing your demo helped a lot. But for some reason, now the only issue in my code is "unexpected type name 'ifstream'", even though I obviously have #include <fstream> at the top :S ... also, int year = strtol(str.substr(54, 4).c_str(), 0, 10); gives the error "implicit conversion loses integer precision"

Comment: Try the `C++.11` version. You shouldn't need to change the function at all, except for maybe give the function a more descriptive name than `process`. Try `std::ifstream`.

Answer (score 0):

From the question above, I think your need is to split the file with separator ' ' or '\t'.
In  c++, you could use boost library.
In boost:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/classification.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  string s = "Hello, the beautiful world!";
  vector<string> rs;   // store the fields in your text.
  boost::split( rs, s, boost::is_any_of( " ,!" ), boost::token_compress_on );
  for( vector<string>::iterator it = rs.begin(); it != rs.end(); ++ it )
    cout << *it << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

or use strtok() function

```
#include <stdlib.h>    
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  char str[] = "Hello, the beautiful world!";
  char spliter[] = " ,!";

  char * pch;
  pch = strtok( str, spliter );
  while( pch != NULL )
  {
    cout << pch << endl;
    pch = strtok( NULL, spliter );
  }
  return 0;
}
```

You can also use `find` or `strchr` functions to find the separator, then you could split it. You could receive the `year` in `vector<string> rs` in the first sample or `pch` in second sample.